# Tailwind CSS is broken in my Laravel app deployed on Google Cloud Run

Tags: css, laravel, docker, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel application that uses Tailwind CSS to Google Cloud Run, but I'm having trouble with the CSS rendering correctly. After deploying the application and accessing it through the assigned URL (https://myapp**.a.run.app/register)  **((the main routes '/' is work fine, but '/login' & '/register' not))**, the CSS is broken and the page looks unstyled.

[image: 1].

Despite all of this, the CSS is still not rendering correctly. Is there anything else I could try to fix this issue?

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring

WORKDIR /app
COPY composer.json .
RUN composer install --no-scripts
COPY . .

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN npm run prod

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

*Checked the HTML to ensure that the CSS files are being included properly.
*Verified that the CSS files are being generated correctly by running npm run prod locally and -*inspecting the output
*Ensured that the tailwind.config.js file is properly configured.
*Checked for any conflicting CSS rules or overrides in my code.
*Inspected the browser's console for error messages related to the CSS and i found this : Blocked loading mixed active content “http://myapp**-nw.a.run.app/build/assets/app-deaf2311.css”.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Hondaman900 yes, it was because of the https, 
I think I have add this to my app.blade:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">